# I think I installed TexLive 2015 but version says 2013

Tags: texlive

`tex --version` returns 2013.

How can I switch to 2015?

I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

In `/usr/local/texlive` I see 2 directories:
"2015" and "texmf-local".

Here's my output of `tex --version`:

> TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
>
> kpathsea version 6.1.1

I used
https://www.tug.org/texlive/
to install.

After running the install script for a long time, it terminated without error.  But I'm not sure if I'm using the new version or not.

Comment: We are going to need more details! What operating system do you use, exactly what did you do to install TeX, what _exactly_ does the version string say (copy-paste)?

Comment: Check your PATH.

Comment: The executables are /usr/bin/tex and /usr/bin/latex.  I don't what other paths to check...?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/59023 for how to install vanilla texlive on ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe in your .profile (/home/username/.profile) is a wrong path.

Comment: OK, the problem is solved after I manually replace all the sym links of `/usr/local/texlive/2015/arch/*` --> `/usr/bin`.  Now the version is 2015.

Comment: Please, make an answer and accept it yourself, otherwise this question will be in the queue of unanswered questions for ever.

Answer (score 2):

When different versions of TeXlive are installed on a system, one of them should be used as default and this is depending on your `$PATH`.

Two solutions:

- you can remove one of the version (in your case the 2013 one)
- modify the symbolic link used to point on the 2015 version as you have done by `/usr/local/texlive/2015/arch/*` pointing to  `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to keep a softlink under `/usr/local/texlive` that points to the current version. You can always have more than one version and make one version current. `current -> /usr/local/texlive/2015`

In your .profile/.bashrc make sure to use the `current` path

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved after I manually replace all the sym links of `/usr/local/texlive/2015/arch/*` --> `/usr/bin`. Now the version is 2015.